# How to preserve class labels during PCA

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pca

How do I preserve labels when doing PCA? I saw 2 tutorials and they leave this completely out: [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/principal-component-analysis-in-python)

Here is my code:

```py
combinedOutputDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(resultArray)

# Separating out the features
x = combinedOutputDataFrame.loc[:, 0:31].values
# Separating out the target
y = combinedOutputDataFrame.loc[:,[32]].values

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2', 'principal component 3'])

finalDf = pd.concat([principalDataFrame, combinedOutputDataFrame[[32]]], axis = 1)
```

How can I be sure in which order *principalComponents* is, though?

```
principalComponents
array([[129.58602603, -21.59786631,  -6.84613849],
           [-39.42963482,  35.19985695,  19.86945922],
           [ 54.81949577,  -5.96905719, -76.57776259],
           ...,
           [ 69.21840475, -35.17983093, -39.66853653],
           [ 18.91508026, -41.64341368,   0.21503516],
           [145.91595004, 127.82236242, 115.14571367]])
```

My end goal is to visualise this, and to color each dot on the plot with corresponding class. But how can I put labels on the data after performing PCA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components are already ordered in descending order from the one which explain the most variance to the one which explain the least. You can check this by printing out the explained variance ratio with pca.explained_variance_ratio_

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# just a random matrix 
rand_matrix = np.random.rand(30,6)

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(rand_matrix)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

Out: 
array([0.28898895, 0.22460396, 0.16874681])
```

Comment: Then how could I label the data after doing PCA? I would like to color different classes for visualisation, after performing PCA.

At first I thought this should work because I input DataFrame to PCA, but it does not matter as it outputs ndarray.

Comment: So, I am confused about what you want to achieve. You can label the PCA components as you did when creating a dataframe, and you can plot them with those labels. From what you write I have the impression that you think that PCA select some of the initial features of your initial dataframe "combinedOutputDataFrame" but this is not the case. After PCA you get n new features columns that are combinations of all the initial features, so you can't trace back pca components to initial features names.

Comment: So I have 32 features and 1000 samples. 33rd feature is used to identify the class.

I do a PCA (1000,32) (no labels) and get (1000,3) right? So each sample has 3 extracted features. But how do I know which sample belongs to which class, when I plot this? I just do a DataFrame.concat having no idea about if these PCA'd samples match labels. I want to plot PCA results, and color each dot to show the actual class.

Comment: Pca is a linear transformation, i.e. just a matrix multiplication, the order of rows is not modified in any way, so the final matrix of shape (1000,32) has the same exact order of your initial feature matrix (1000,3). You can simply attach the labels to the final matrix again to plot the different classes.